# Google Maps Javascript API not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load Google Maps API in a webpage with the `<script>` tags at the bottom of the body with the #map element referenced above.

Get the error alert: "This page was unable to display a Google Maps element. The provided Google API key is invalid or this site is not authorized to use it. Error Code: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError"

My API KEY is definitely correct; I have checked it multiple times.

I have chosen to accept request from the following referrers 
*.mywebsite.com/* 
*.mywebsite.com* 
www.mywebsite.com/* 
www.mywebsite.com/test  // this is the url I am trying to load the map on.

I have tried without the API Key Reference and without the Init callback and the map loads intermittently. Sometimes it will load (around 20% of the time), other times it doesn't and I get the following console log - ReferenceError: google is not defined;

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="/js/map.js"></script>
```

My map.js file containing the map config

```
var map;
var mapLatLng = {lat: 13.778182, lng: -0.23676};
var mapStyle = [maps style options] // https://snazzymaps.com/style/38/shades-of-grey
var mapMarker = '/img/marker.png';

function initMap() {

  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyle,
  {name: "Styled Map"});

  var mapOptions = {
    center: mapLatLng,
    zoom: 10,
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
  }
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: mapLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!',
  icon: mapMarker
});

//Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call the GMap script as *async defer*, so you are not sure that the script will be downloaded and executed before *map.js*. And your *map.js* script call the GMap API.

Could you test first without the *async defer* attribute. If it's ok, just move all your initialization code in the initMap function, it should work :

```js
function initMap() {
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: mapLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!',
      icon: mapMarker
    });

   //Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
   map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
   map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
   var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyle, {name: "Styled Map"});

   var mapOptions = {
        center: mapLatLng,
        zoom: 10,
        scrollwheel: false,
        navigationControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        scaleControl: false,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
      }
   };
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for the use without the api key thanks. seem to be getting "TypeError: window.initMap is not a function" in the console though.

Comment: If you declare the `initMap` outside scopes, it will be created in the `window` object. Try to execute `window.initMap` in the console. If it's undefined, your `ìnitMap`declaration is probably scoped. In this case move its declaration or use `window.initMap = function() {...`.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as answered ?